# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Query string parameter determines class of body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking for an example of ASP.NET Core complex model binding with two twists. One is that the class of the body is determined by a query string parameter, but the query string parameter does not determine the type.

```
[HttpPut("api/Certificates/activities/state")]
public IActionResult PutState([FromQuery] string stateId, [FromQuery] int activityId, [FromQuery] string agent, [FromQuery] Guid registration, [FromBody] object body = null)
{
    ...
    return NoContent();
}
```

The query parameter that determines the class of the body is `stateId`, but its value does not exactly contain a type name. Rather, the scenario is as follows:

1. If `stateId` is equal to `"LMS.LaunchData"`, then the body should be validated as a `LaunchData` object.
2. If `stateId` is equal to `"status"`, then the body should be validated as a `Status` object.
3. Otherwise, the body should be a plain object.

The second twist is that the known classes of the body that will post to this endpoint have nothing in common. In other parts of the application, they serve entirely different purposes. I am posting my two special body types below for you to see that they have nothing in common.

LaunchData.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmploymentModules.Models
{
    public class LaunchData
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("registration")]
        public Guid Registration { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("contextTemplate")]
        public Context ContextTemplate { get; set; } = new Context();
        [JsonPropertyName("launchMode")]
        public string LaunchMode { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("launchMethod")]
        public string LaunchMethod { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("returnURL")]
        public string ReturnURL { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("launchParameters")]
        public string LaunchParameters { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("entitlementKey")]
        public EntitlementKey EntitlementKey { get; set; } = new EntitlementKey();
        [JsonPropertyName("moveOn")]
        public string MoveOn { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class EntitlementKey
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("courseStructure")]
        public string CourseStructure { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cmi5Result.cs

```
    
using EmploymentModules.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static EmploymentModules.Helpers.ScoreValidators;

namespace EmploymentModules.Models
{
    public class Cmi5Result
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("score")]
        [ScoreValidation]
        public Score Score { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("success")]
        public bool? Success { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("completion")]
        public bool? Completion { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("duration"), RegularExpression("^(P((?<Years>\\d+)Y)?((?<Months>\\d+)M)?((?<Days>\\d+)D)?)(T((?<Hours>\\d+)H)?((?<Minutes>\\d+)M)?((?<Seconds>\\d+((.)?(\\d)?(\\d)?))S)?)$")]
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("extensions")]
        public ResultExtensions Extensions { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ScoreConverter))]
    public class Score
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("scaled")]
        public decimal? Scaled { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("raw")]
        public int? Raw { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("min")]
        public int? Min { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("max")]
        public int? Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultExtensions : DynamicObject
    {
        [Range(0, 100), JsonPropertyName("https://w3id.org/xapi/cmi5/result/extensions/progress")]
        public int? Progress { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^(Tested Out|Equivalent AU|Equivalent Outside Activity|Administrative)$"), JsonPropertyName("https://w3id.org/xapi/cmi5/result/extensions/reason")]
        public string Reason { get; set; }

    }

    public class Status : Cmi5Result
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("launchModes")]
        public List<string> LaunchModes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Don't try to automap the body content, instead read it by yourself and deserialize the correct class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions.

1.You can Deserialize Object in action like following:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult PutState([FromQuery] string stateId, [FromQuery] int activityId, 

    [FromQuery] string agent, [FromQuery] Guid registration, [FromBody] object body)
            {
               
                    var model = new Object();
                    switch (stateId)
                    {
                        case "LMS.LaunchData":
                            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LaunchData>(body.ToString());
                            break;
                        case "status":
                            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(body.ToString());
                        break;
                        default:
                        model = body;
                            break;
                    }
                return Ok(model);
        
            }
```

test body:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "score":{
        "raw":1,
        "min":0,
        "max":2
    }
}
```

result:
[image]

2.You can also add `stateId` to Object body.And use Model Binder.So that the class of the body is determined by `stateId` in the Object body.
Here is a demo:

Controller(Add `[ModelBinder(typeof(DataBinder))]` before `object body`):

```
//use ModelBinder to Bind object body
public IActionResult PutState([FromQuery] string stateId, [FromQuery] int activityId, [FromQuery] string agent, [FromQuery] Guid registration, [FromBody][ModelBinder(typeof(DataBinder))] object body)
        {
            return Ok(body);
    
        }
```

DataBinder:

```
 public class DataBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }


            var model = new Object();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                var mydata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body.Result);
                
                var stateId = mydata["stateId"].ToString();
                switch (stateId)
                {
                    case "LMS.LaunchData":
                        model = mydata.ToObject<LaunchData>();
                        break;
                    case "status":
                        model = mydata.ToObject<Status>();
                        break;
                    default:
                        model = mydata.ToObject<Object>();
                        break;
                }
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

test body(Add `stateId` to body):

```
{
    "stateId":"status",
    "success": true,
    "score":{
        "raw":1,
        "min":0,
        "max":2
    }
}
```

result:
[image]